# Spring MVC set dropdown default selected not working

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, dropdown

I was having some problem when trying to set selected value for drop down in Spring MVC. Here is my controller:

```
// hardcoded ID 2 here, originally the ID will be retrieved from database
model.addAttribute("bloodGroupId", 2);
return "myPage";
```

In my JSP, I am trying to loop the list and set default selected option:

```
<td align="left" width="10%">
        <form:select path="bloodGroupId">
            <c:forEach var="bloodGroup" items="${bloodGroupLookUp}">
                <form:option value="${bloodGroup.bloodGroupId}" label="${bloodGroup.abrvBloodGroup}"/>
            </c:forEach>
        </form:select>
    </td>
```

However, the dropdown just keep selecting at the first item as default. Is there anyway to bind it to show the selected one? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring MVC form:select selected value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202368/spring-mvc-formselect-selected-value)

Comment: So I have to use a Map?

Comment: Hi I figured out already. Need to set some condition at JSP. Thanks!